# How to mark textview as strike through in Expandable Listview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

When I call Action Mode on expandable listview item, one of the options is to mark as done.

What I do in onActionItemClicked, where child_clicked is just view that was long clicked:

```
TextView row = (TextView) child_clicked.findViewById(R.id.todoTitle);
if (todo.getStatus() == 1) {
    int count = mSQLiteHelper.MarkTodoAsComplete(Id, mSQLiteDatabase);
    row.setPaintFlags(row.getPaintFlags() & ~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
} else {
    int count = mSQLiteHelper.MarkTodoAsActive(Id, mSQLiteDatabase);
    row.setPaintFlags(row.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
}
```

Row layout looks something like this:

```
<LinearLayout> 
    <TextView android:id="@+id/todoTitle"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But nothing is happening, no errors. What have to be done here to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With expandable listiview approach mentioned before doesn`t work. You should just pass new object to Hashmap like this. No need to add strike through, if you set it already in adapter.

```
   Todo newTodo;
     if (todo.getStatus() == 1) {
     newTodo = new Todo(todo.getTitle(), todo.getCategory(), 0, todo.getId_() );
    int count = mSQLiteHelper.MarkTodoAsComplete(Id, mSQLiteDatabase);

   } else {
   newTodo = new Todo(todo.getTitle(), todo.getCategory(), 1, todo.getId_() );
  int count = mSQLiteHelper.MarkTodoAsActive(Id, mSQLiteDatabase);

                }

            switch (todo.getCategory()) {

                case 0:
                    L1.set(childPosition, newTodo);
                    ChildList.put(Headings.get(6), L1);
                        break;

...
}

 mTodoExpandableAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

That is it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

apply this code to the TextView of your ExpandableListView item.

```
tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: you also need to do this in your adapter implementation because the `ExpandableListView` recycles, so as user scrolls or w/e you will lose your style.  The `ExpandableListView` supports the checks automatically if your view is also `Checkable`.

Comment: The thing is, inside adapter this already implemented and works well. But, somehow, on the fly does`t work. @Arsalan Shah suggestion doesn't work either.

Comment: @EasyGamer. yes. Its because on scrolling the view of the list gets refreshed. You will have to make the list remember which list item's TextView was strike through. For this you will have to store the positions of those positions of the list items having strike through TextViews and use the same code pasted above to assign them the strike through.